# PHP a href link with print or echo

Tags: php, echo, href

I have quick question about a herf link in php field.
When I try to make a href link in php field by using echo or print,
it does not work the link.
Could you see the code briefly? Thanks!

```
if(isset($_SESSION["manager"])){
    echo "<div id=\"login_link\">
            Welcome Admin!<br>
            <a herf=\"storeAdmin/admin_logout.php\">Log out</a>
            </div>"; 
    }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It should be href="...." not "herf".

For more info about the **a** tag you can take a look here: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp

Answer (score 1):

Here I have updated your code

```
if(isset($_SESSION["manager"])){
        echo '<div id=\"login_link\">
                Welcome Admin!<br>
                <a href=\"storeAdmin/admin_logout.php\">Log out</a>
                </div>'; 
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

1. It is `href=""` not `herf=""`
2. It is good practice to refrain from using relative links, as it is likely to cause issues in more complex sites. Use something like `href="/root-path-to-your-stuff/storeAdmin/admin_logout.php"`

Answer (score 1):

also just a suggestion, you can always use ' inside of " instead of having to cancel your quotes.  Atleast it works for me

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem but its because I was using

echo "".htmlspecialchars($errorMessage)."";

removing the htmlspecialchars fixed it for me.